# Set object for key string to plist iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi guys I been having trouble and checked online for few days and still cannot get a piece of code to work how I want it to. Im trying to get a string that is in a "alertTextField.text" and set it to a key @"kUsername" in the plist_path. I have been trying different ways but when I check the NSLog it doesnt set and only shows kUsername even though in the plist file there is a key named kUsername.  Can someone help me and tell me what I can be doing wrong so I can learn a little more?

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
 if (buttonIndex == 0){
       UITextField *alertTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"alerttextfiled - %@",alertTextField.text);
        NSMutableDictionary *userlist= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:PLIST_PATH];
        NSString *username = [userlist objectForKey:@"kUsername"];
        [userlist setObject:alertTextField.text forKey:@"kUsername"];
        NSLog(@"alerttextfiled - %@",username);
    }}
@end
```

Comment: Update your question with actual relevant code. Provide sufficient context to the code.

Comment: updated sorry about that

Comment: "when I check the NSLog it doesnt set and only shows kUsername" Because that is what you are saying to do. `NSLog(@"alerttextfiled - %@",@"kUsername")` That is _always_ going to log `"alerttextfiled - kUsername"`. What else could it possibly do? That has got to be silliest `NSLog` call in the history of `NSLog`.

Comment: Updated, it shows what the user has entered for username but can't figure out how to set the user input to setobject forkey kUsername so the log reads the new input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself, needed to use writetofile.

```
[userlist writeToFile:PLIST_PATH atomically:YES];
```